# Can't import a file into another file in Rust

Tags: file, import, rust

C++ veteran trying my first steps in Rust. I have a small project with 3 files:

**main.rs**

```
mod person;
use person::*;

fn main() {
    let mut pp = Person::new(); // Person struct used here
    pp.name = "Malcolm".to_string();
    println!("{}, {}, {}",
        pp.name, pp.place.street, pp.place.number);
}
```

**person.rs**

```
mod addr;
use addr::*;

pub struct Person {
    pub name: String,
    pub place: addr::Addr // Addr struct used here
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            name: "John".to_string(),
            place: addr::Addr::new()
        }
    }
}
```

**addr.rs**

```
pub struct Addr { // won't use any other struct
    pub street: String,
    pub number: i32
}

impl Addr {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            street: "Boulevard".to_string(),
            number: 33
        }
    }
}
```

However, when trying to compile, I receive this error message:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `addr`
--> src/person.rs:1:5
|
1 | mod addr;
|     ^^^^
|
= help: name the file either person/addr.rs or person/addr/mod.rs inside the directory "src"
```

I can't really figure out what's wrong, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [`use crate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html#use-paths) path to keep you files in the same directory. This may be handy if you'll eventually want to re-use `Addr` in other modules without being coupled to `person`. In your example, try the following.

1. In `main.rs`, add `mod addr;` to make the `addr` module visible to the root.
2. In `person.rs`, change:

```
mod addr;
use addr::*;
```

to:

```
use crate::addr;
```

Answer (score -1):

From the error message it looks like your addr.rs file is in the wrong place (src/addr.rs?). The following project layout would work:

```
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   ├── person
│   │   └── addr.rs
│   └── person.rs
```

As would:

```
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   ├── person
│   │   └── addr
│   │       └── mod.rs   <== this is addr.rs renamed
│   └── person.rs
```

Modules are hierarchical and form a tree from the crate root, either `src/main.rs` or `src/lib.rs`.

The crate root can reference a module that is declared in another file, e.g.

```
mod module1
```

It then expects to find either a file called `src/module1.rs` or `src/module1/mod.rs`.

But if `module1` references another module, `module2`, it is expected to be in either `src/module1/module2.rs` or `src/module1/module2/mod.rs`, nested under `module1`.

See [Separating Modules into different files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html) in the Rust Book.

For `main.rs` to also use `Addr`, `person.rs` needs to declare the `addr` module public:

```
pub mod addr;
```

Then `main.rs` can reference it like:

```
let myAddr = person::addr::Addr::new();
```

or

```
use person::addr;
// ...
let myAddr = addr::Addr::new();
```

Comment: Why can't I have all 3 files in the same directory? What if `main.rs` also instantiates an object of type `Addr`?

Comment: @Rodrigo Please read https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html it has all the answers.

Comment: @Rodrigo, It's because each module can only own modules in certain places. `main.rs`, `lib.rs` and `mod.rs`-s can each own any files in the immediate directory they're located in, or another module in `/name_of_module/mod.rs`. This means you can have `main.rs` beside either `foo.rs` or `./foo/mod.rs`. There's a new feature which is mentioned in this post, which allows a module to own any other modules in a folder named after it. If we take the above `./foo.rs` example, `foo.rs` could own `./foo/bar.rs`.

Answer (score -1):

As the other said, but maybe it wasn't very clear to the beginners. As I'm myself a beginner, maybe I can help to explain.

you can walk through the structure of the module having the main module as the base. If you have something like:

```
├── src
│   |--- main.rs
│   |--- addr.rs
│   |--- person.rs
```

if you import all the modules in main.rs

```
//main.rs
mod addr;
mod person;
```

inside person you can walk to addr like

```
//person.rs
use crate::addr;
```

Or using super

```
//addr.rs
use super::person;
```